# How to save a HTML page on the SDCard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have displayed a `HTML` page in `WebView` using a `URL` and I created a menu to save that `HTML` page, but I don't know how to save that page on the `SDCard` or in device memory so that we can keep it for future use.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this even I have apply some logic but not able to do this. Can any one post some code for this or if any body have related example, please post.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this link](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/) to save the webview cache to the SD-Card

and then in the properties of the webview set it as follow:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Comment: hii what ever you have given link its not opening

Comment: Check this 
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/

Comment: i have create menu i want just click on save button and it shud save to sd card